# How a React component is able to access props not passed to that component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've following three components and passing `Hello` to `Parent.js` component but `Child.js` is also able to access it. So could anyone please explain me the reason behind that ?

**App.js**

```
import Parent from "./Parent";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Parent
        test="Hello"
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Parent.js**

```js
import Child from "./Child";

export default Child;
```

**Child.js**

```
const Child = ({ test }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>From Child Component: {test}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

[image: Edit the-code-is-working-fine-in-codesandbox-but-showing-error-while-doing-in-the-id]

Comment: Despite the names, you *don't* have a parent and a child component here. Your top-level `App` actually only renders `Parent`. And `Child` is simply the same thing as `Parent` (because you've imported and re-exported with no changes). Nowhere do you render `Parent` with `Child` as a child, and in that situation you indeed couldn't access a prop passed to `Parent` inside `Child`.

Comment: Okay, understood.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code in `Parent.js`:

```
import Child from "./Child";

export default Child;
```

just re-exports `Child` as the default export from `Parent.js`. It doesn't create a new component, it just provides a second way to use the **same** component, as though you did this:

```
const Parent = Child;
```

So when you use `Parent`, you're actually using the `Child` component in `Child.js`.

If you want a separate component, you need to actually create a separate function or class, for example:

```
import Child from "./Child";

export default function Parent() {
    return <Child />;
}
```

If you had that in `Parent.js`, `Child` wouldn't see `test` because `Parent` doesn't pass `test` to it. You could pass it on, of course:

```
import Child from "./Child";

export default function Parent({test}) {
    return <Child test={test} />;
}
```

> How a React component is able to access props not passed to that component?

It can't. Your code is passing `test` to `Child` (via the other name you've given it, `Parent`).

Comment: Very nice explanation, you got my doubt cleared. And I hope you liked the question and it was not a silly question.

Comment: Could you please provide any documentation for the same if available ?

Comment: @Kundan - MDN has some documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules). I also go into `import` and `export` in detail in Chapter 13 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at your book for sure.

Answer (score 0):

probably because the parent component is export child > you are just aliasing

Answer (score 0):

Your `Parent` component is the same as the `Child` component. They have the **same definition**